# Sentinel - monitoring new answers to old questions

Tags: app, answers, posts

First there was [Natty](https://stackapps.com/q/7049/43403) - looking for new answers to old questions that aren't actually answers, and posting them in [a chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics).

Then there was [Sentinel](http://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com).

Sentinel is the web dashboard for Natty. The bot sends data on all posts it reports to Sentinel, where a permanent record of them is kept.

To aid the moderation effort, Sentinel has some write features built in, including the ability to flag the post directly from its Sentinel record.

### Features

- Keeps permanent records of reported posts, including their full text, author, and the detection score the bot assigned them.
- Records feedback on each post (true positive, false positive, etc).
- and obviously, writes to the Stack Exchange API.

### Source

Sentinel is built with Ruby on Rails. Its source code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/ArtOfCode-/Sentinel).

Comment: I haven't looked at the code yet, but does it have real time updates?

Comment: @TinyGiant real time updates for what?

Comment: For the updating of the dash board through AJAX or WebSockets. After waiting for a bit, I realized it doesn't.

Comment: @Tiny I don't think there's any data coming in at the moment, but no it doesn't.

Comment: 6 - 8 somethings?

Comment: @TinyGiant I can add it to the list, but it's a fair amount of work for a relatively small gain. 6-8 weeks would be accurate, and add a couple for luck.

Comment: Trying to get an understanding of who is running the Sentinel server at https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com nowadays.  Bhargav Rao mentioned that ArtOfCode passed it to Undo, but that Undo probably passed it to someone else, and we're not sure who.  It's been down for 4 days now in case someone can get it back up and running.