# PLACEHOLDER - Stack Overflow NAA NLP

Tags: app, placeholder, stackoverflow

An app similar to [Natty](https://stackapps.com/questions/7049/natty-bringing-10k-moderation-to-all) and [DharmanBot](https://stackapps.com/questions/8594/naabot-bot-which-finds-and-flags-problematic-answers-on-stack-overflow), with the difference that classification of NAAs is done with the help of [natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) using a deep learning model trained on existing Natty reports, my own NAA flags, and possibly also other users' flags.

No source code or link yet, this is a work in progress. I will need to test the model extensively to make sure it's good enough to use, and if so proceed to build an actual app, hence the need for a StackApp to access StackExchange APIs. An idea could also be to integrate the functionality of this app into Natty.

<sup>If you want to contribute in any way, you can ping me in [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).</sup>